# Angular 2 - It is possible to bind the app component in existing DOM without erasing HTML content?

Tags: bind, angular

I try to bootstrap my main angular component in a pre-executed HTML Document.
This is my existing DOM :

```
<html>
<head></head
<body>

<!-- this is my template generated with Symfony -->
<div ...>
 <ul>
   <li><angularComponent></angularComponent></li>
   <li><angularComponent></angularComponent></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to bind my Main App Component (or Directive) on body, or on the main div, without replacing my pre generated content (with symfony).

It is possible ? Have you other solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is done by adding `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the template of your Angular `AppComponent`s template, but AFAIK this is not supported on the application component, only on child components.

You could try to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` on the `AppComponent` und use `<content></content>` instead of `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

I haven't tried this myself yet.

Comment: I have tried the two solutions, unfortunately, it doesn't work in my configuration. I think I will work on ViewEncapsulation to better understand the mechanism. I Thank you.

Comment: `<ng-content>` and `<content>` are a slot where the Angular component projects it's child elements to. With  `<ng-content>` projection is done by Angular. With `<content>` it's done by the browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content (may need polyfill). AFAIK for security reasons Angular intentionally doesn't support that for the root element.

Comment: I understand the security issues, I hope the team have or will have a solution for this purpose. Single Page Applications are not yet widespread and I think many people would like use Angular2 with an existing and pre generated DOM / template. Furthermore, the <content> element is now deprecated. I have a very sad and inelegant solution to my problem : I caught pregenerated DOM with Jquery in a global Javascript variable, and I inject it into my Angular2 Component's template using an auto called closure. This can cause problems with a large DOM content.

Comment: Right, `<content>` will be replaced by `<slot>` (AFAIR) with limited selection feature.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i haven't found any good answers to this question, here's the (hacky) way I did it:

```
document.getExistingContentByTag = function(tagName){
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0];

    if(!target || !target.tagName) return '';

    return target.innerHTML;
}
```

And to render the template:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: document.getExistingContentByTag('my-app')
})
```

So it pulls the content of the my-app tag, does its magic and writes it back.

Comment: This does not work if there is any angular code in the element, because innerHTML always returns the HTML tags in lower cases (at least in Chrome), because HTML is case insenstive. So for example, if you have a [(ngModel)] attribute it does not work afterwards and an error is thrown, because ngmodel is unknown (`Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`).