# How to bootstrap an app in Angular 2 without replacing contents of the original website?

Tags: angular

I am not exactly making a single page app, but i rather make an Angular app that ships components, so that a user can just place a tag on their website and Angular app recognizes the tag and implements the component accordingly.

Let's say I have an Angular app that only implements one component `test`, and it should be possible to place the component in any place on the page:

```
<body>
    ...
    <test></test>
    ...
</body>
```

Or like this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        ...
        <test></test>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

and so on.

However, if I bootstrap the App module in the `body` DOM element, the whole content of the `body` is replaced. So what I need is the way to implement one Angular component in the app without replacing other content of the page.

I guess a proper way to do this would be injecting and manipulating some of `templateRef`, `elementRef` or `viewContainerRef`, but I am not sure which one exactly is it and what should I do with them.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Basically the problem is similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/424nwn/using_angular_2_without_it_being_a_single_page_app/), but the code in the examples is obsolete.

Comment: while you can run Angular for a part of your page, you still need to define a whole part of your DOM tree for angular purposes

Comment: @Maximus Isn't there a way to work around it, like asked in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993936/angular-2-it-is-possible-to-bind-the-app-component-in-existing-dom-without-era ? Because it was working like charm in AngularJS, so I feel kinda bummed that now I can't use new Angular because it can't do what AngularJS can without forking it and explicitly teaching it to do so.

Comment: try asking on github, maybe a core contribute will share an insight

Comment: I think Angular2+ is just not the right framework (and doesn't intend to be) for what you try to do.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the answer. I wrote a bunch of logic and components in Angular, what would be the most painless way to make use of them without rewriting the whole app for a new framework?

Comment: @haemhweg not sure what you ask for. Either build an Application in Angular2 the Angular2 way or don't. Angular2 is a framework to build large-scale applications, it's not to enrich web pages. For that Angularjs 1.x is a better fit.

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993936/angular-2-it-is-possible-to-bind-the-app-component-in-existing-dom-without-era

Comment: You may have respective directives for this purpose, accordingly to which action will act upon.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue [Transclusion for root component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11336)

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6143

Answer (score 2):

As posted in the comment you probably don't want to be using Angular2/4 in this specific type of application. React is probably the MVC you're looking for if you want to add small pieces in existing pages. Other than that you'll probably just want to be coding using jquery or similar. Angular2/4 doesn't really work as added pieces to existing, and is made for large-scale web-app development (hence the huge initial app size).

If you really want to use Angular2/4 then you'll want to transfer the previous code into your Angular Framework. Either you'll transfer the old page into your Angular2/4 Framework or have to rewrite your Angular code.

Sorry, since I'm sure this wasn't the answer you were hoping to hear.

Comment: There shouldn't be a huge initial app size. I'm not using TypeScript and can't really tell, but what I saw from benchmarks quite some time ago, initial app size isn't huge (at least not if properly built with minification, tree-shaking, ...).

Comment: In comparison to ember it's nearly twice the size out of box, compared to react it's more than five (last I checked, with rx, and before angular4 split off animations). It's still relatively small, don't get me wrong, but it's still a lot larger than other MVC frameworks out of box. At the same time, as your get a larger code base it tends to be more efficient (and larger apps end up smaller than other MVC).